# How to check whether a char from a multidimensional array is equal to a const char?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I think the title makes it self explanatory. The actual code is quite long but here's and example that I think matches the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 char multiDArray [5][5];
 multiDarray[1][2] = 'x';
 char barrier = 'x';
 int main () {
  if (multiDArray[1][2] == barrier) {
    cout << "It works". }
  }
```

This doesn't give me an error, but nothing happens when I run the program.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's that `.` after `"`?

Comment: The line `multiDarray[1][2] = 'x';` is invalid outside of a function definition.

Comment: `This doesn't give me an error`???

Comment: This looks like it is not the complete code you're working with. Please post the whole function.

Comment: There is also an issue with capitalisation.  The array that you set the value in is not the same as the array you define or the one you test.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the code you provided so that it compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char multiDArray [5][5];
char barrier = 'x';

int main ()
{
    multiDArray[1][2] = 'x';
    if (multiDArray[1][2] == barrier) {
        cout << "It works";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You'll see here (http://ideone.com/MFn9yM) that it does indeed work.

**Output:**

> It works

It's possible you are seeing no output in your larger program because you are not flushing the output buffer (using `std::flush` or by including a newline).